# Define a target is in another target

Tags: matrix, 3d, vuforia

I am using Vuforia to recognize targets via the camera.

I've got to markers: small target and much bigger target.
I need to define that the smaller target is placed inside the bigger target.

I already can see two markers in time. I can get 4x4 matrix of the targets.
One of the ideas was to make a projection of the 4x4 to the z0x plane to both of targets and than define does the one projection matrix contain the second one.(but I do not know how to do it)

Some code how I am getting the matrix

```
- (void) renderFrameWithState:(const Vuforia::State&)state projectMatrix:(Vuforia::Matrix44F&)projectionMatrix {
//some opengl initializations
 for (int i = 0; i < state.getNumTrackableResults(); ++i) {
        // Get the trackable
        const Vuforia::TrackableResult* result = state.getTrackableResult(i);
        const Vuforia::Trackable& trackable = result->getTrackable();

        Vuforia::Matrix44F modelViewMatrix = Vuforia::Tool::convertPose2GLMatrix(result->getPose()); //getPose() returns 3x4 matrix
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projecting the matrix to the same plane is easy - you already have this code if your have a working Vuforia sample. It is something like this:

```
SampleUtils::multiplyMatrix(&projectionMatrix.data[0],
                            &modelViewMatrix.data[0] ,
                            &modelViewProjection.data[0]);
```

HOWEVER, I do not think you really need to project them, you can simply compare the two matrices you get from Vuforia.

One way of checking if one matrix is inside the other (not 100% accurate, but quite simple) is by the center point and size. Meaning - take the center point of one (the x and y position values in the matrix are modelViewMatrix.data[12] and modelViewMatrix.data[13] respectively), and see if that point, after adding the width and height is within the borders of the second matrix (again, by the second matrix center point, width and height).

Comment: So I should state.getTrackableResult(i) for each of the targets, convertPose2GLMatrix(result->getPose()) to get 4x4 matrix and do all calculations you described above  with 4x4 matrix? As I understand it doesn't consider a plane, and if the smaller target will above the second one for a 10cm it may say me that the smaller one is inside the second one, is it correct?

Comment: I do not think this is correct. But, you can use the method I offered you for the projected matrix as well. Anyway, I think you should try one of the methods or both - it should be quite easy. If it helps, see here for some some explanation of their matrix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061257/get-pure-view-matrix-in-vuforia

Comment: Could you please give a link to the 4x4 matrix description. I can't find it, I want to ensure the 12 and 13  are a center and also want to know other values to use somehow(it might be useful)

Comment: Sure - but yes, 12, 13 and 14 are x, y and z of the center point. This is a general explanation: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/.  How the matrix itself is built is up to the implementation, and you are using Vuforia's. But I strongly recommend experiencing yourself - if you are not sure, add some number (200?) your matrix.data[12] and watch the result... This hands-on approach will bring you faster to the result you want.

Comment: Thank you. I checked out the link but still have one more question - how to get a width and hight in Vuforia? Should I use matrix math as well?

Comment: As I said the link is general. If you look at the "Translation matrices" section, you will see that the last column (which is actually cells 12, 13, 14, 15) contains the x, y and z at cells 12, 13, 14. You can get the width and height from Vuforia 'getSize' api on the imageTarget. You should by now have what you need in order to try out the solution, my friend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140081/discussion-between-denfav-and-yakobom).